# knocked/flipped/lying on its side

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, writing

> The man in the wheelchair crashes into a wall. People rush over to help the man, who is screaming in pain, his wheelchair **lying on its** side.

Could I used *knocked* or *flipped* rather than *lying* in this case, and does it sound like the man in the wheelchair is screaming due to it *being on its side* rather than screaming due to something else?

Comment: This forum isn't intended to give writing advice - but it seems plain enough to me that the man's injury and the position of the chair are results of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting 'and has' after 'pain'.

'The man in the wheelchair crashes into a wall.  People rush over to help him, who is screaming in pain and has his wheelchair knocked/flipped/lying on its side.'

Any of the 3 states is fine to describe the wheelchair.

I would imagine that the man is screaming 'in pain' and not 'because' his wheelchair is on its side.